# iphone app run on device

Tags: iphone, device

WHats the easy way to accomplish this ..??

I am developing an iphone app and have also got my app installed in my ipod touch. I showed it to a friend of mine and he wants me to install in his ipod touch. I loaded the xcode project in his mac and everything works fine. Now I need to make this app run on his device. How can I do this ..???

For some reason I don't have access to the my personal mac through which I installed on my device.

Also his device is not sync to his itunes and he does not want to sync it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Installing Apps Wirelessly](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979-CH1-SW11).  Don't worry about the enterprise account requirement, that's not necessary any more.

You'll need to register your friend's device in the Provisioning Portal and digitally sign the app with a provisioning profile that references that device.

Comment: I am bit confused....can I install without the need of my development machine. I am travelling and will not have access to my develoment machine for few more days.

Comment: Not without jailbreaking your friend's device.  In order to run an iOS application it has to be digitally signed.  You cannot do this without the private key you generated when setting up your development environment.  Unless you exported the private key and brought it with you, you are out of luck.

Comment: This link explins detail solution to my problem.  http://www.theevilboss.com/2009/06/iphone-sdk-development-on-multiple.html. However just a thought...can I make xcode look at a different private key instead of the one I used for creating the provisioning profile. If I can achive this then I should be able to install app on device...right ?

Comment: I don't think a second private key is possible.  Only the designated team agent can sign ad hoc builds, and you can only have one team agent per developer account.  I don't know what you mean by "multiple developmental certificate".  If your developer account is set up as a company and not an individual, you may be able to get it onto his device by registering yourself as a second developer, then using that key to install it through Xcode using Build and Run.

Comment: Tried and tested..it works .!!! I tried the steps mentioned in above link.it works...!!! Thought of sharing so that you don't waste time looking around for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend's device needs to be added to your provisioning file. If your friend's device UDID is not registered with your developer account and not in the provisioning file, then it won't install.

Comment: I can't get the access the development machine . So I tried it with my friends machine. As I  told you before, I have copied all the files to his machine and app runs fine on simulator. I addedd my friend's UDID and downloaded the provisioning file. When I drop this file on xocde, organizer window opens and I see error as "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain." How to fix this ..????

Answer (score 0):

You will need access to your personal Mac for your Developer certificate and/or the private key for your Developer certificate.

Then after you add your friend's iPhone's UDID in the iOS Developer Portal, you can create a mobileprovision that will allow you to build an app that can be be installed on this iPhone.

You can sync this app and the mobileprovision file to the iPhone via iTunes, or slightly more complicated if you don't want to sync, put on a server with the mobile provision packaged in an appropriate format for wireless installation.